# iphone code - use a custom table instead of default one

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i'm using a default style table,
i want to add more rows to the table, how can i customize it?

code:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

// Leave cells empty if there's no data yet
if (nodeCount > 0)
{
    // Set up the cell...
    ARecord *aRecord = [self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = aRecord.lDate;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = aRecord.WNum;

    // Only load cached images; defer new downloads until scrolling ends
    //(!aRecord.appIcon) - use icon
    if (!aRecord.appIcon)
    {
        if (self.tableView.dragging == NO && self.tableView.decelerating == NO)
        {
            [self startIconDownload:aRecord forIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
        // if a download is deferred or in progress, return a placeholder image
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"];                
    }
    else
    {
        cell.imageView.image = aRecord.appIcon;
    }

}

return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that I understand the question. The number of sections and rows in the table are controlled by the table view's [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) (in most code examples, that protocol is implemented by the view's controller, but it could be a separate object).

The code you've posted comes into play much later in the process: after the view has determined how many rows are present, total, and which are currently on-screen, and needs to render those rows. But, in general, it and the other methods of the [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol are how you'd customize the appearance and behavior of the table. (Along with the properties of the view itself.)

Answer (score 1):

The number of rows in the tableview is determined by what you return in

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

if you return 500 there, you'll have a 500 row table.

Answer (score 0):

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tblArray count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifer=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer];
    if(cell==nil){
        cell=[self myCustomCell:CellIdentifer dicToSet:[tblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    }
    return cell;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)myCustomCell:(NSString*)CellIdentifer dicToSet:(NSDictionary*)dicToSet
{
    UITableViewCell *cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44) reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifer] autorelease];

```
UIImageView *imgV=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 2, 40, 40)];
[imgV setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[dicToSet valueForKey:@"Photo"]]];
[cell addSubview:imgV];
[imgV release];




return cell;
```

}